# It is possible to use the new ActiveRecord::Attributes API in a PORO?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I usually include ActiveModel::Model into some PORO (for example for a  FormObject::SignUp). I've read about the new Rails 5 ActiveRecord::Attribute API, and I thought I will be able to use it for simpler casting, but not luck.

For example, given

```
class FormObject::SignUp
  include ActiveRecord::Model
  include ActiveRecord::Attributes

  attribute :birthday, :date
  validates :birthday, presence: true
end
```

I got an `` NameError: undefined local variable or method `reload_schema_from_cache' for FormObjects::SignUp:Class `` exception when I try to instantiate it.

It is not expected to be used standalone? Thanks

Comment: A big part of activemodel attributes is dealing with the database (e.g translating the attribute to a real sql query) so it makes sense to me if this doesn't work .

Comment: @Joel_Blum they could have done it to work as a virtual attribute.. I mean, unless you read / write to the db it shouldn't explote.

Answer (score 4):

### Rails >=5.2

This is now possible in Rails 5.2.

> As of Rails 5.2 (#30985), ActiveModel::Atrributes is now available to use in POROs (at least POROs that include ActiveModel::Model)...

- Reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28020#issuecomment-456616836
- Documentation: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activemodel/ActiveModel/Attributes#attribute_names-instance_method

### Rails <5.2

Utilizing the gem `ActiveModelAttributes`is the only easy way I've been able to find to do this. Depending on your use case, it will probably make sense to use that gem or take a different approach.

Here is the gem: https://github.com/Azdaroth/active_model_attributes

Side note: I got feedback that link-only answers can disappear. If this link disappears, then this answer does indeed become invalid since that will likely mean the gem dosen't exist anymore.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16744662)

Comment: I'm not sure that applies in this case. it isn't a link to a solution per se, as much as it is a link to a library. Still, I mentioned the gem by name. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

[`ActiveModel::Attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) is available as of Rails 5.2 ([PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/30985)).

Try this:

```rb
class FormObject::SignUp
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes

  attribute :birthday, :date
  validates :birthday, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) it seems that this module cannot be used stand-alone, as it makes a lot of assumptions (mostly about a schema-backed model).

Even if you try with the [`define_attribute` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e37a8b9e84a9dd532485ee7945c9d053b9f9d86/activerecord/lib/active_record/attributes.rb#L222), you still need to provide implementation for other class methods, like `attribute_types`.

What's wrong with using `ActiveModel::Model` in Rails 5?

```
class Poro
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :foo
end
```

Comment: Of course I want to still use it, the idea is to also use the typecasting feature.. for example, if you do Poro.new.foo = '2017-02-15' it will cast it automatically to a date.. just that. I've glimpsed above the documentation and it's not clear that it shouldn't be used standanlone, do you have a link?

Comment: This is precisely why I am looking for this behavior as well.  ActiveModel is a very powerful pattern.  Its a shame that ActiveModel won't work in this fashion, yet.

Comment: How can you use @object.attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

I've submitted an issue and they replied that it's not supported currently, but it will be in the future.

Link: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28020#event-963668657